# Help evaluating an integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I am stuck on the following real integral:

$$
\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}x_1 \dots \int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}x_N \ \left( \sum_{j=1}^N x_j \right)^{N k - 1} \left( \prod_{l=1}^N x_l^{k-1} \right) e^{-a \sum_{m=1}^N x_m},
$$

with $N \ge 1$, $a>0$, and $k>1$.

I could evaluate it numerically and it would be fine, but I am hoping I can do this analytically. Is there a way to do this? Maybe some way to exploit the fact that it is symmetric under exchange of the $x_i$'s, or some integral transform to disentangle the sums/products?

Many thanks for the help. The behaviour for $N \rightarrow \infty$ would also be interesting, but keeping general $N$ is most helpful.

Edit for context:

This appeared in an inference problem (some genetics data). For $N=1$, I am trying to evaluate:

$$
p^{(1)}(t \vert t^{*}) = \int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}x p(t \vert x) p(x \vert t^{*}) 
$$

with:

$$
p(x\vert t) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(k) \theta^k t^k}x^{k-1} e^{-g/(\theta t)}
$$

I keep $t \in [0,\infty)$, with $p(t)$ uniform. This yields (being careful with limits etc):

$$
p(t \vert x) = \frac{\theta (k-1)}{\Gamma(k) \theta^k t^k}e^{-g/(\theta t)}
$$

Consider now having $N$ independent datapoints $\{ x_i \}$. In that case:

$$
p(\boldsymbol{x} \vert t) = \frac{1}{(\Gamma(k) \theta^k t^k)^N} \left( \prod_{i=1}^N x_i^{k-1} e^{-x_i /(\theta t)} \right)
$$

$$
p(t \vert \boldsymbol{x}) = \frac{\theta \Gamma(k)^N}{\Gamma(Nk-1)} \frac{(\sum_{i=1}^N x_i)^{Nk-1}}{\prod_{i=1}^N x_i^{k-1}} p(\boldsymbol{x} \vert t)
$$

Plugging this into:

$$
p^{(N)}(t \vert t^{*}) = \int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{x} p(t \vert \boldsymbol{x}) p(\boldsymbol{x} \vert t^{*}) 
$$

Yields an integral with the structure above.

Comment: May I ask the context in which  appears this integral ?

Comment: Hey @ClaudeLeibovici, I have edited the question to provide context.

Comment: Thank you for giving the context. Cheers :-)

Comment: Perhaps first do cases $N=1, N=2, N=3$.